# Sparse data with many labels

Tags: machine-learning, classification, regression, sparse-matrix

I have this dataset in which I have to predict whether the customer will give 2nd order given he has ordered his 1st and if yes in how many days the customer will give another order after his 1st order? In training data if the customer does not give another order it's label is N(meaning No order) and if it gives another order after 180 days its label is L(meaning long). If the 2nd order is between 0 to 180 days its label is the number of days between 1st and 2nd order.(eg 13,27,45,60,135,etc). I have to predict **exactly** the number of days the customer will give another order or (N- no order and L- order after 180 days).The features are just 1's and 0' containing 646 columns (sparse data).

First I am confused what kind of problem is this.It seems like it is the mixture of classification and regression problem.1st I have to classify whether it belongs to N,L or between 0-180 days.then if the order is between 0-180 days I have to predict **exact** number of days the customer will give another order.If what I am thinking is correct what should be my approach.Any other suggestions are welcome.

PS: there are 7474 rows and 646 columns containing sparse data with 0's and 1's

Comment: I will suggest you post this question in https://datascience.stackexchange.com/. StackOverflow should be programming related and this problem, from what I see, is more related with the data science field as it is right now.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would start by doing a simple classification first.
In that, you try to "weed out" the short-term re-orders form the longer term/no buy customers.

Make sure that you have a reasonable distribution across these categories, to get a decent result.

Afterwards, you can then start looking at the data that has specific days only, and then perform regression on this subset.

As for the sparsity of the dimensions, you could try dimensionality reduction, with for example PCA, or LDA, to get a better representation of your data, and not waste unnecessary resources (you can also use an embedding layer, for example).